# Load new set of geometry per frame in Vulkan

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I try to develop a render server thats draw an any scene per request.
I need to destroy the previous scene and load new one when new request is incoming. But also I need create a new pipeline with new `VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo`.

Can I do without pipeline recreation ?

IMO the best approach is to create just 1 VBO and 1 IBO, but I dont understand how to use `offset` in IBO to perform drawing. Is it possible ?

Comment: So you expect that the only difference between these "any scene"s will be... the vertex arrays? How does that make sense? If you're changing vertex inputs, you have to be changing the vertex shader that *processes* those inputs, right? That's going to require a new pipeline. Not to mention blending and the like.

Comment: Scene structure, mesh structure, mesh vertice attributes, texture formats and shaders code are always the same. Blend state does not change. Only new meshes and textures are loaded.

Comment: "*mesh vertice attributes*" Then why do you need to change `VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo`? If the attributes are all the same, then the format should be the same too. As should the number and description of the buffers. So... which parameters do you want to change?

Comment: Actualy I need load a new meshes and textures but remove old. The new count of the meshes and textures may be different.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. There is no "count of the meshes" parameter in `VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo`. So why do you need to change it?

Comment: Reading the comments, I'm not really sure anymore: what's the problem?
Do you simply want to just draw something else? Isn't that achievable simply by passing another `VkBuffer` to `vkCmdBindVertexBuffers` (and potentially freeing the old if necessary) holding the new vertex data?

Comment: I made a big mistake and you helped me understand why. Thanks a lot for the discussion.  I read the spec and solved the problem.